# Angular, trouble using ngIf, async and Observable to wait until data is ready to display content

Tags: json, angular, observable, angular6

I am new to Angular and I am stuck. I can't seem to get this to work and I think I'm just making some mistakes on how I'm implementing the Observable. Currently I am using a local json file as my data source, but in my main project I will connect to an external API. I have stripped everything down to make it as basic as possible and still no luck.

Here's campaign.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

    import { CampaignService } from '../campaign.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-campaign',
      templateUrl: './campaign.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./campaign.component.css']
    })
    export class CampaignComponent implements OnInit {

    $campaign: Observable<any>;

      constructor(
        private campaignService: CampaignService
      ) {}

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getCampaign();
      }

      getCampaign(): void {
        this.campaignService.getCampaign().subscribe((data) => {
          this.$campaign = data;
          console.log(this.$campaign);
        });
      }
    }
```

Here's the template html, campaign.component.html

```
    <div *ngIf="($campaign | async) as campaign; else loading">
    <!--this never loads-->
      {{campaign.shortName}}
    </div>

    <ng-template #loading>
    <!--this is all I see-->
      Loading stuff in ngIf...
    </ng-template>

    <br>
    <br>
    <!--this works so I know the data loads and that my json file is formatted correctly-->
    <p>Outside of ngIf works: {{$campaign.shortName}}</p>
```

Here's the service, campaign.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
    import { map} from 'rxjs/operators';

    const endpoint = 'assets/api.json';

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })
    };

    @Injectable()
    export class CampaignService {

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

      private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res;
        return body || { };
      }

      getCampaign(): Observable<any> {
        const url = endpoint;
        console.log(url);
        return this.http.get(url).pipe(
          map(this.extractData));
      }

    }
```

Thanks for taking the time to help with this.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question contains several issues related to observables and the async pipe, and would be difficult to provide a single correct answer. The only thing I can think of is to provide you with a tutorial on how to use the async pipe. https://alligator.io/angular/async-pipe/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  getCampaign(): void {
    this.campaignService.getCampaign().subscribe((data) => {
      this.$campaign = data;
      console.log(this.$campaign);
    });
  }
```

The above assigns the data value to the property `this.$campaign` but you've declared that property to be an observable.

```
<div *ngIf="($campaign | async) as campaign; else loading">
<!--this never loads-->
  {{campaign.shortName}}
</div>
```

*$campaign* is not an observable so the async pipe resolves to undefined. The condition is always *false*.

```
<!--this works so I know the data loads and that my json file is formatted correctly-->
<p>Outside of ngIf works: {{$campaign.shortName}}</p>
```

The above works because *$campaign* was assigned the data value.

```
<p>Outside of ngIf works: {{($campaign | async)?.shortName}}</p>
```

You should always use `async` in the template for observables.

You can simplify the component by assigning the observable in the constructor.

```
  constructor(private campaignService: CampaignService) {
      this.$campaign = campaignService.getCampaign(); 
  }
```

Alternatively, you don't have to use `async` if you subscribe and assign the data.

```
<div *ngIf="campaign; else loading">
<!--this never loads-->
  {{campaign.shortName}}
</div>

<p>Outside of ngIf works: {{campaign?.shortName}}</p>
```

Comment: You can find the modified version here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyceq1

Comment: @cgTag, I opted to use your alternate suggestion of removing `async` entirely and everything works perfectly.

Comment: @C.Lightner if this solved your problem, then can you accept the answer.